# How does a wireless charger transmitter detect the power required by the receiver?

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

[image]

The image above shows a 20W phone charger wireless transmitter.

The transmitter details stated

> Charging power: 5W/7.5W/10W/15W/20W automatic identification on its receiver coil)

How does the transmitter detect the power needed by the receiver?

Is it through the number of coils in the receiver? For example, a phone which can be charged with high power has its own special receiver with more number of coils and conversely, a phone which can be charged with low power has its own special receiver with low number of coils.

The receiver is also made up of coils as shown. I am quite confused.

Comment: Data can be sent back through the magnetic field to be received by the transmitter in some designs. Do you have a schematic for the one you show? The transmitter will have no idea how many receive coils are used.

Comment: They talk. I would not be surprised if they use NFC, but they could use pretty much anything.

Comment: Qi allows data transfer. Check WPC for details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a picture from [OVERVIEW OF WIRELESS POWER AND DATA COMMUNICATION](https://www.wirelesspowerconsortium.com/data/downloadables/1/6/7/2/charlie-wu-nxp-qi-developers-forum-overview-of-wireless-power-and-data-communications.pdf) explaining how data transfer from the Qi receiver to the Qi transmitter is used to regulate the power magnetically coupled to the receiver: -

[image]

This is just one commercial example. There are other variants of this and, I've also developed my own prior to the emergence of Qi. It also back-modulated the magnetic field so that the transmitter could regulate power transfer.

> *How does a wireless charger transmitter detect the power required by
> the receiver?*

The receiver tells the transmitter either by modulating the magnetic field (so that the transmitter can detect this as data) or by sending a separate signal. The "separate signal" can be achieved optically or via RF wireless but, is not limited to either; if you wanted, you could "talk" to the transmitter ultrasonically if you wanted.

> *Is it through the number of coils in the receiver?*

No, it's impossible for the transmitter to tell how many coils the receiver has and, even if it could detect this, power has to be regulated on demand from the receiver hence, a basic data transfer mechanism has to be employed.